# Oracle SQL: pick the right values for an update

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have two tables. One contains a list of tickets, one contains all the comments made in each ticket. A ticket has an owner, the comment makers are tracked by their user_id.

I want to set the owners of the tickets to the users that make the first comment. The base of the script is this:

```
update incident inc
inner join incidentdescription incdes on 
  inc.inci_id = incdes.inci_id
set inc.owner_id=incdes.user_id;
```

However, each ticket has several comments. I can track the first comment by the incdes.creationdate. I need to have the oldest one. However, how can I make sure that at the set part, I pick the incdes.user_id from the oldest comment from each ticket?

Comment: Does Oracle `update` support `join`?  Your syntax looks more like MySQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff A big NO... But there are tricks like using the join in a MERGE USING Clause OR Inline Views

Comment: please show table schemas, sample data, and expected results.

Answer (score 3):

You can try any one of this in Oracle

**Normal Update**

```
UPDATE
      INCIDENT
SET
      INCIDENT.OWNER_ID =
          ( SELECT
                INCIDENTDESCRIPTION.USER_ID
           FROM
                INCIDENTDESCRIPTION
           WHERE
                INCIDENT.OWNER_ID = INCIDENTDESCRIPTION.USER_ID )
WHERE
      EXISTS
          (SELECT
                INCIDENTDESCRIPTION.USER_ID
           FROM
                INCIDENTDESCRIPTION
           WHERE
                INCIDENT.OWNER_ID = INCIDENTDESCRIPTION.USER_ID);
```

**Using Inline View (If it is considered updateable by Oracle)**

**Note**: If you face a non key preserved row error add an index to resolve the same to make it update-able

```
UPDATE
      (SELECT
            INCIDENT.OWNER_ID AS OLD,
            INCIDENTDESCRIPTION.USER_ID AS NEW
       FROM
                INCIDENT
            INNER JOIN
                INCIDENTDESCRIPTION
            ON INCIDENT.INCI_ID = INCIDENTDESCRIPTION.INCI_ID) T
SET
      T.OLD     = T.NEW;
```

**Using Merge**

```
MERGE INTO
      INCIDENT
USING
      (SELECT
            T1.ROWID AS RID,
            T2.INCI_ID
       FROM
                INCIDENT T1
            INNER JOIN
                INCIDENTDESCRIPTION T2
            ON INCIDENT.INCI_ID = INCIDENTDESCRIPTION.INCI_ID)
ON
      ( ROWID = RID )
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
    UPDATE SET INCIDENT.INCI_ID = INCIDENTDESCRIPTION.INCI_ID;
```